# C Linux -input to fgets makes infinity loop

Tags: c, linux, fgets

I have a strange problem.  I am using C on Linux.

I am trying to get input from stdin using fgets.

It works fine, but when I input a string like:

`x^2,1,2` (then enter)

or

`x^2+x^1,1,2` (then enter)

It just behaves like the fgets is still working, and it doesn't finish that operation.

I tried to print something after the fgets, but the code is not getting to that line, it just stays in the fgets!

If I input:

`x^2+1,1,2`

or

`x^2+x^1+2,1,2`

it works!!

I think it may be related to the final ^1 ^2... I don't know what's happening

The code:

```
char* ReadInputIntegral(FILE *stream)
{        
    int i; //assistent variable

    //allocate 'input' in size of LEN(=512)
    char *input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*LEN);

    //in case allocation failed
    if(input==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //put the user input from command line to 'input'
    if( fgets (input , LEN , stream) == NULL )
    {

        //in case error during reading from standard input
        free(input);
        return NULL;
    }

    //  case of user insert empty command
    if(input[0]=='\n' || input[0]=='\0')
    {
        printf("INPUT:2");
        free(input);
        return NULL;
    }

    //replace the '\n' in the end of input command to '\0'.
    for(i=0; input[i]!='\n'; i++);
    input[i]='\0';

    return input;
}
```

Comment: I tried three times, but I cannot figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce any problem which resembles what you describe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 512

char* ReadInputIntegral(FILE *stream)
{        
    int i; //assistent variable

    //allocate 'input' in size of LEN(=512)
    char *input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*LEN);

    //in case allocation failed
    if(input==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //put the user input from command line to 'input'
    if( fgets (input , LEN , stream) == NULL )
    {

        //in case error during reading from standard input
        free(input);
        return NULL;
    }

    //  case of user insert empty command
    if(input[0]=='\n' || input[0]=='\0')
    {
        printf("INPUT:2");
        free(input);
        return NULL;
    }

    //replace the '\n' in the end of input command to '\0'.
    for(i=0; input[i]!='\n'; i++);
    input[i]='\0';

    return input;
}

int main(void) {
    char * input = ReadInputIntegral(stdin);
    printf("Input is: %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

which gives:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src$ ./integral
hi there
Input is: hi there
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src$ ./integral
x^2, 1, 2
Input is: x^2, 1, 2
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src$ ./integral
x^2+x^1,1,2
Input is: x^2+x^1,1,2
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src$
```

Compiling and running on a Debian Linux system gives identical results.

As for "infinity loops", you only have one single loop in your code extract. This could go haywire if input exceeds the length of the buffer, since then `fgets()` will not include an `'\n'`, but you assert that your buffer length is `512`, so this should not be a problem with any of the input you are attempting.

Mandatory comments about not casting the return from `malloc()` and not using `sizeof(char)` apply as always.